# Adjusting the content to fit on every Iphone

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout

i can't manage to adjust all my content on the iphone 6s aswell as on the iphone 4.. on the iphone 6s the label font size is very small compared to the screen size, and on the iphone 4 not all of the content fits on the screen. 
I tried solving this problem using auto layout, but there is no difference between the iphone sizes. only between ipad and iphone landscape and portrait..

i dont want to adjust this with code, is there a way to do it in the storyboard?

Comment: Include some relevant code and post a screenshot of how your app is looking on both phones. No one knows what trouble you have

Comment: manage using scrollviews. in iphone 4 screen will scroll for extended part of screen in vertical situation and for horizontal i have idea to fit all elements in all devices by using proportional width and height. if you still need solution in this manner reply or if you found any solution then ignore.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Size Classes to distinguish **iPhone 4** vs **iPhone 5.5**. Size Classes can only distinguish these cases (see picture below). You must check the specific screen size in you code

[image]

Comment: then i have to do it in Code i guess.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, please check iphone screen size in your code !

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with auto layout and constraints? You do not have to open every simulator to see how does it look on different devices. And you can do it in storyboard.

You can open `Storyboard` -> click on the assistant editor [image] -> Now where it says "Manual"
[image]
enter image description here on the upper thing click on "Preview"
[image]

And now you can mess around more easily with constraints and see right after change how it looks like on different screen sizes.

Comment: i am already trying to do it with auto layout and constraints for 2 days, but the font size wont change its size between iphone 4s and iphone 6s.